# the present perfect referring to habitual actions

Tags: present-perfect

Can the present perfect be used to refer to habitual actions as follows?

> John always has a smoke when he **has taken** a shower.

Could the sentence convey the idea that his having a smoke habitually follows his shower?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, it's fine but slightly confusing.  Do you mean "John always has a smoke **after** he has taken a shower", or "... **while** he is taking a shower"?

Comment: I mean "after he has taken a shower." Doesn't the present perfect indicate the smoke follows the shower?

Comment: Your sentence as it stands should be *John always has a smoke when he* ***takes*** *a shower*. And it, on its own, is ambiguous as to whether the smoking happens during or after the showering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the present perfect in that way:

> John (always) gets a hangover *when he's had* too much to drink (the night before).
>
> John gets a hangover when he's had too much to drink.

The habitual aspect is expressed by the simple present **gets a hangover**.  The condition **when he's had too much to drink** expresses perfective aspect: when John has crossed that particular threshold.

> John always kisses the ground once he has safely landed.
>
> John kisses the ground once he has safely landed.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say:

> John always has a smoke **after** he has taken a shower

then I suggest using "after" instead of "when".  While it is true that the present perfect does imply one thing happens after another, because "when" represents an ambiguous time frame it can be slightly confusing.  Its' always possible you used the present perfect by mistake.

For example, consider this sentence with the simple present:

> John always has a smoke when he **takes** a shower.

After a shower?  During the shower?  We have to guess.  But if you say:

> John always has a smoke **after** he takes a shower.

there is no confusion.  A similar example:

> You must make a decision when the sands in the hourglass **have run out**.

What if I make a decision *before* they run out? Is that okay?  Again, it's not clear, because "when" does not adequately restrict the time frame.

The point is, if you want to be sure that you get the meaning of a sentence across with 100% accuracy, you can't always rely on the present perfect.  Using the right adverbs of time can be helpful.